# How do I associate a parent node with all of its children in an event listener? jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, event-listener

I'm not extremely good with JavaScript, as I've only been coding as a hobby for a little over a year now, so forgive me if this question seems stupid. I'm also new to posting here on StackOverflow.

Anyway, I'm trying to put an event listener on a dynamically created element that has child nodes.

Example:

```
<div class="div">
    <div class="div2">
         Content in Div2
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
         Content in Div3
    </div>
    Content in Div
</div>
```

That would be the HTML setup. For the JavaScript (I am using jQuery too, if there is a better way to handle this) I am using this code (because the elements are dynamically generated):

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if (e.target.className === "div"){
        //Run this code
    }
});
```

But what if I want to have that code run even when `div2` and `div3` are clicked? I know I could loop through the DIVs and say:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if (e.target.className === "div" || e.target.parentNode.className === "div"){
        //Run this code
    }
});
```

However my actual code has a lot of stuff going on and it would look like a jumbled mess. Is there a more optimal way to go about this?

I feel like I'm missing something very simple

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your elements are created during run time, they would not available while registering events for them in ready state, so that in this context you have to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Try,

```
$(document).on('click','[class^="div"]',function(){
 //your code here.
});
```

And in the above code, i have used [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), so that you could easily select the elements which have class name starts with div and write the events for the same.

Comment: Cant we use a specific class name for the elements that are generated dynamically and bind events?

Comment: @RachitDoshi Yes, we can do that,  But OP's requirement is little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div with the class "div" to be clickable along with everything inside it then you just have to do:

```
$('.div').on('click', function () {
    //DO SOMETHING
});
```

The above will make the container div and everything inside clickable.

If you want all divs inside only to be clickable then you would do this:

```
$('.div div').on('click', function () {
    //DO SOMETHING
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/simonlevasseur/82m9Y/